# Navigating Universal Deep Links on iOS: Opening the App or Redirecting Based on Installation Status from Instagram Stories

Tags: ios, swift, instagram, deep-linking

We've successfully integrated deep linking into our iOS application using Universal Links. However, when users click on a link shared in an Instagram story, we currently redirect them to our website instead of opening the app. Our client prefers a dynamic approach: opening the app if it's installed and redirecting to the website if it's not. We're particularly interested in the alert mechanism observed in some companies, where users are prompted with "Instagram X wants to open the application" when the app is installed. Despite our research, we haven't found a conclusive solution. If anyone has experience with iOS deep linking and can provide guidance on achieving this flow, we'd greatly appreciate it. Thank you for your assistance!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using Associated domains instead of Universal links, here is the documentation [link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/supporting-associated-domains)

You have to follow these things while doing that

1. Make sure your website confirms to the HTTPS protocol as apple suggests
2. Include their domains in the project as shown here, make sure you've included all the combinations of your website's address with and without "www.". But don't include "https://" before your web address in any of them.
   [image]
3. Generate one AASA - Apple App Site Association file and share it with your web developers and ask them to put it inside the /.wellKnown folder or within project files.
4. Mention your app ids properly within AASA file like this
   [image]

Comment: Hey, theja thank you for your answer but this is what we have implemented in our project and it's called 'Universal Link' if I'm not mistaken. Currently,  when you click in our link, it works in other cases like opening our app in Notes, Whatsapp, or any website. The problem is that when you click our link on Instagram stories, Instagram doesn't redirect users to our app, it redirects users to our website, even if the user has already installed.

Comment: got it, I'm also facing the same issue, I think it won't work as expected with Instagram, Facebook etc, basically any product with Meta, but somehow it is working with whatsapp as you said, Also it won't work with the Twitter. Apple puts heavy restrictions on these products as they are heavy data miners. I think its related to some permissions compliances these products are not following which apple proposes.

Comment: Agree. But I'm seeing that some companies have successfully added this feature. But how? There is one possibility that I can see: They're using both Universal Link and URL scheme at the same time. For example, if the user is redirected from Instagram, they're using URL Scheme approach and showing users an alert about "Instagram wants to open X Application." It's so acceptable if the user has installed the application. But what if the user hasn't installed the application yet? Is it possible that they know if user hasn't installed the app yet when using URL Scheme approach?

Comment: Hello again, Thejas. I found a solution. I used both Universal Link and URL scheme simultaneously and write a article about how to used they on medium: 
https://medium.com/@cemnisan/how-to-automatically-open-your-app-from-instagram-stories-using-universal-link-and-url-scheme-71650ee90a8b

Comment: Hello, @CemNisan, that's good to hear that you've found a solution, I have one doubt regarding that, will it be able to redirect to the App Store if the app is not installed, and will you be able to get that redirecting url when you install the app from any of such links?

Comment: I think that you referred "Deferred DeepLink", right? I've searched it and I've found that it's very complicated when we want to implement it by ourselves. So If you want to implement it, I can recommend you to use "Branch.io" or "Appflyer".. And I think that "Appflyer" is free when you want to use their DeepLink feature.